# 08S01: ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server; TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054)

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

We have automated CI tests against a SQL Server database in Azure, using ODBC 17.5.2.

These tests have been working for ages, with no change to our code, ODBC driver nor the database instance.

But today the test started failing with:

> [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)

Any idea what's changed on the Microsoft side?
It must be something very very recent – this week, possibly today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears Microsoft added some new firewall settings to Azure SQL Server.

By default, these new firewall settings **disabled public access** => ODBC could not connect to the DB.

I manually reset them to the following values and the tests started working again:

[image: azure sql settings]